# How to run tests from parent mvn module?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have the following structure in mvn.

```
| pom.xml (parent)
|
|
+----- module A (common classes)
|      |   pom.xml
|      |
|      \---src
|          +---main
|          |
|          \---test
|              +---junit
|              |
|              \---integration
|
+----- module B (web app)
|      |   pom.xml
|      |
|      \---src
|          +---main
|
+----- module C (web app)
|      |   pom.xml 
|      |
|      \---src
|          +---main
```

Module A is a module inherited by all subsequent modules (B, C, ...). This module has common functionality and junit/integration test cases. It's not a web app.

Module B is a web app. It has a dependency on Module B.

Module C is a web app. It has a dependency on Module B.

Our Jersey rest/api code lives in Module A. In this way no matter what module we deploy we will always have access to the rest/api.

So far I have managed to configure Maven FailSafe plugin in Module C to stand up a tomcat instance when I run the top (parent) pom.xml (ie: mvn verify).

However, Module C is not able to see the integration tests from Module A. I have tried configuring maven-jar-plugin (http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html).

In the pom.xml of Module A I have:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

and in Module C I have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>SCCommon</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <version>9.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how I can run those integration tests in Modula A when mvn is running Module C failsafe plugin.

Note: integration tests are named *IT.java so it gets picked up by the failsafe plugin.

Is there any other way of doing this or Am even using the right plugin?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you need to make `<include>**/*IT.java</include>` that's indicator to have a separate integration test module where you should put your integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

If module C contains a dependency on A with the *tests* classfier you can refer to that dependency in the `<dependenciesToScan>` attribute of your maven-failsafe-plugin (since 2.15) configuration.

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#dependenciesToScan

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>it</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <dependenciesToScan>
            <dependency>com.group:A</dependency>
        </dependenciesToScan>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Using your maven-jar-plugin configuration I ended up with an empty tests archive. I had to change the pattern to `<include>**/*IT.class</include>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have added the test classifier and the dependenciesToScan tag to the configuration. This is all in Module C  pom now. I also changed the extension from .java to .class for the maven-jar-plugin to work. Checked and the archive is not empty. Now when I run mvn verify I get -> Failed to execute goal on project Module C: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx.connect:ModuleC:war:9.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.xxx.pathways.common:ModuleA:jar:tests:9.1.0-SNAPSHOT. However when I go to Module A, under target, I can see the ModuleA-9.1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar file

Comment: @allegjdm93 Did you do a `mvn install` before running `mvn verify` to install Module A into the local mvn repository so other projects can use the dependency? Or perhaps there's a typo in the POM file somewhere.